# I have a configuration problem with MATE and Linux. Which Stack Exchange site should I post to?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I'm trying to ask which site I should post this question below.

I have FC30 and the [MATE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MATE_(software)) desktop, and I'd like to make it look as close as possible to Windows without making my own theme. I'm using the Windows XP theme, but it shows the title bar menu items crunched together. For example, there is no space between "Applications" and "Places" in the menu bar. This happens only on some applications, others are more functional. If I click on *File*, the drop down does not show the menu item I'm hovering over.

I tried [Cinnamon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cinnamon_(desktop_environment)), but it takes about 5-10 minutes to load. I really liked the [Trinity Desktop Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trinity_Desktop_Environment), but the interest in that seems to have died. I don't necessarily need it to be MATE, but I want the environment to start in under a minute or two after the machine has loaded. I'd like it to have the Start->Run paradigm. And I want to completely *not* use any dark theme anywhere, because it's too hard on my eyes to see a light gray on a slightly darker shade of grey.

I appreciate any help the community can offer.

[image]

Comment: Have you read [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289905)?

Comment: Re *"I tried Cinnamon, but it takes about 5-10 minutes to load"*. Even using rotating rust, the total system startup time, is about 60 seconds for me on relatively low spec hardware. Using SSD is about half that, but it tends to end in ***catastrophic failure*** (losing *all* files) after a few months.

Comment: What is "FC30"? Do you mean [Fedora 30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_version_history#Fedora_30)? Fedora 30, [CoreOS edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fedora_%28operating_system%29#Editions)?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on MSE instead of MSO?

Comment: There are really two questions here.  First, which sites would consider this question on topic.  Second, which would be most likely to provide a useful answer.

Comment: This question should be on Meta Stack Exchange.

Comment: Under Linux Mint I'm seeing startup time with Cinnamon of about 10 seconds using pretty antiquated hardware (although with a new disk drive - which is why that machine runs Mint - old Windows laptop, drive died, replaced, didn't feel like paying MS $$$ for a license)

Comment: @user4642212 That was the point of this question. In the past, I've posted a question related to getting say

Comment: @Woodsman post it on [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/). In the future if you have "which stack exchange can I post this on" type questions, recommend posting them on [MetaSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) rather than MetaSO.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think in *principle* that Unix Stack Exchange may be a good spot, but in *practice* you would have better success on Reddit.  There is a whole cadre of people out there who make it a goal of theirs to theme/skin Linux as a whole other OS, which may suit your needs better than Stack Exchange which is more Q&A oriented.

Comment: If you turned it into a software recommendation question, it might be something that could be asked on [SoftwareRecs.SE]. You'd need to read their Help Center first. Don't ask me; I haven't read it.

Comment: It's not really a software recommendation, @CodyGray.  Skinning a Linux OS to make it seem like another is a whole level of effort and exercise that can take literally *months* to get right.  Having done this in the distant past, I can say with confidence that the Stack Exchange model is a poor fit for questions like this.

Comment: @CodyGray that would only work if there's a readily available solution that you can simply install, rarely with skins this is the case.

Comment: @Makoto I'm not asking for an exact replica, or even something very close. Some time in 2010 KDE had a version, I think before Plasma that I really liked. But I think it's reasonable to expect commonly used applications, even the menu bar to not be crunched together--without spending days learning how to do your own theme.